# Jhipster dataUtils.downloadFile errors out for content with non ASCII characters

Tags: file, download, jhipster

I have been trying to use the inbuilt `dataUtils.downloadFile` function from `JHipster` on the angular side. This accepts a content string and content type and let the user download the content as a file.

I noticed that, it can easily process content which contains `ASCII` character. However, it fails to process `UTF-8` character set.

This is the error I get :

> **Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window'**

Am I missing something or is there a way to get around with it?

Currently i have to go through my file to replace all `UTF-8` only chars to `ASCII` but that would be tedious.

Thanks for reading..

EDIT: 
Below is the field definition.

```
    {
        "fieldName": "troubleshooting",
        "fieldType": "byte[]",
        "fieldTypeBlobContent": "text"
    }
```

Here is the angular code which tries to convert the string to base64 and then download.
The problem is not with base 64 encoding. It is fine. The problem is with content format. If the content contains UTF-8 only chars, then it fails. In other cases I get the file downloaded successfully

```
download(appliance: Appliance) {
    const applianceObj = JSON.parse(appliance.troubleShooting);
    const prettyPrinted = JSON.stringify(applianceObj, null, 2);
    const data = this.base64Utils.encode(prettyPrinted);
    this.dataUtils.downloadFile('application/json', data, appliance.applianceType);
}
```

Comment: Which type of blob did you select in JHipster for your entity field: any, image or text? If you did not generate code and only tried to use dataUtils.downloadFile, you must take into account that it expects content to be base64 encoded, so server should base64 encode it.

Comment: Hi @GaëlMarziou please see the edit. I tried to answer your question